# slide vertical and horizontal

Tags: jquery, slide

I am looking for a slider that can scroll vertically and horizontally. with the arrows I would like slide in the other areas. is this possible, if so how?
here I have a picture:

http://msdev.de/1.png

Comment: So you mean the user clicks an arrow, and the box slides in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/pJqTn/6/)

```
<button id="left">&#9668;</button>
<button id="bottom">&#9660;</button>
<button id="right">&#9658;</button>
<div class="block"></div>



div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
  top:50px;
}


var slideDistance;
var slideSpeed;

//Change this Properties
slideDistance = 200;
slideSpeed = 500;


$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=" + slideDistance + "px"}, slideSpeed);
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=" + slideDistance + "px"}, slideSpeed);
});

$("#bottom").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "+=" + slideDistance + "px"}, slideSpeed);
});
```

Comment: @herrsaidy I updated my code, just change the javascript variables for your needs

Comment: I want to build a fullscreen website. in a navigation point I can let slide content in all direction. when I click to the left then comes from the left content when I click to the right content comes from the right and from the bottom as well. but all should be fullscreen.
like this: http://nicinabox.com/superslides/ but not only horizontal

Comment: @herrsaidy ok, i understand now, try this plugin, i think its perfect for you http://jquery-plugins.net/full-content-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-single-page-websites